# convert an element then append it to another parent?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a question about html and jquery. I am using the blogspot platform and I want to create a slideshow using "Image Widget". The code results after adding 3 image widgets are below. The elements are `<h2>` as title, `<a href>` with img anchor and then a caption.

```
<div class="sidebar section" id="faux">

<h2>Slide 1</h2>

<a href="#">
<img alt="Slide 1" height="540" id="Image1_img" src="images/slide1.jpg" width="960">
</a>
<span class="caption">slideInLeft</span>


<h2>Slide 2</h2>
<a href="#">
<img alt="Slide 2" height="540" id="Image2_img" src="images/slide2.jpg" width="960">
</a>
<span class="caption">slideInRight</span>


<h2>Slide 3</h2>
<a href="#">
<img alt="Slide 3" height="540" id="Image3_img" src="images/slide3.jpg" width="960">
</a>
<span class="caption">slideInTop</span>

</div>
```

I have a plan to use Nivo slider, then I read that nivo slider markup are:

```
<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">

<a href="#"><img src="images/slide1.jpg" alt="" title="Slide 1" data-transition="slideInLeft" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="images/slide2.jpg" alt="" title="Slide 2" data-transition="slideInRight" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="images/slide3.jpg" alt="" title="Slide 3" data-transition="slideInTop" /></a>

</div>
```

My question are:
1. is it possible to change `<span class="caption">slideInLeft</span>` to `data-transition="slideInLeft"`  then append it to `<img>` element?
2. in the same case i want to change `<h2>Slide 1</h2>` to `title="Slide 1"` then append it to `<img>` element too...

Thanks in advance, sorry for my english :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per my understanding i have javascript code for you 
us this javascript on load

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#faux img").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("data-transition" ,$(this).parent().next(".caption").html());
$(this).attr("title" ,$(this).parent().prev("h2").html());
    $(this).parent().next(".caption").remove();
    $(this).parent().prev("h2").remove();
});

});
```

Comment: wow, you are rocks.... great script :) it works for me. 

but is it possible to remove `<h2>Slide 1</h2>` and `<span class="caption">slideInLeft</span>` after append it to `<img>`?

Answer (score 0):

in plain javascript:

```
var attribute = document.getElementById('attribute').getAttribute('data-transition');
var spans = document.getElementsByClassName('caption').setAttribute('data-transition', attribute);
var img = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
img.innerHTML = img.innerHTML + spans;
```

where there is an element with the id attribute which contains an data-transition attribute